# Avoiding ambiguous methods caused by extends/implements

Tags: java, generics, operator-overloading

I have a convenience function which takes various types of objects and converts them in a serializable sort of way. For example, JSON-like objects are converted into JSON:

```java
public static <T> String process( List<T> list ) {
    if( list instanceof JSONArray ) {
        return ((JSONArray) list).toJSONString( );
    }
    // stringify the list
}
public static String process( JSONAware object ) { // array, map, value, ...
    return object.toJSONString( );
}
```

I'm using the `org.json.simple` library, so `JSONArray extends ArrayList implements JSONAware`. But that means that when I send a JSONArray, I get:

> reference to process is ambiguous

I'm aware that it could equally go to either method, which is why I have equivalent implementations in both.

Clearly I could replace both functions with one which takes arbitrary `Object` types, but that would remove a lot of compile-time checking which I'm not happy about. I could also rename one of the functions to force a particular choice, but that complicates the API.

Is there some way I can force a particular choice, or make it obvious to the compiler that it doesn't matter which method gets called in these cases?

Comment: Wy do you have the second one - you can just call the toJSONString on the object

Comment: It's a reduced example of the code. Think of it like serialize-over-http; it also stores information about the type of object which was sent. I'm using it so that a web-based interface can show information about arbitrary objects (and the type of the object is included in the sent data)

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
public static void process(JSONArray array) {
    process((JSONAware) array);
}
```

while it is not a general solution, it would solve it in this case.

---

In this example

```
public class Example {

    static class A {

    }

    interface B {

    }

    static class C extends A implements B {

    }

    static void process(A a) {

    }

    static void process(B b ) {

    }

    static void process(C c) {
        System.out.println("process C called");
    }

    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        process(new C());
    }
```

prints

```
process C called
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it didn't work; the error simply moved to be between the JSONArray and List versions, instead of the JSONAware/List versions.

Comment: @Dave I would check which version of Java you have.  I tried Java 7 update 51.

Comment: Ah, I'm stuck with some legacy code running on 6. Could this be a fixed feature?

Comment: I don't have Java 6 on my system any more. I suggest you try the latest version of Java 6 and see.

Comment: Hmm, the code you posted works fine unless A is made generic; adding `<T>` to the `process(A)` function and `A` class makes it fail unless `C` also defines a type when extending `A`. So the bug seems to be caused because org.json.simple extends a raw `List` instead of `List<Object>`.